# A private constructor is a default constructor or not?

Tags: java

According to the [Java Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9), a default constructor is a constructor with no-args that is provided by the compiler if you do not define one:

*The Java Language Specification*:

> **8.8.9. Default Constructor**
>
> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor  is implicitly declared. The form of the default constructor for a top level > class, member class, or local class is as follows:
>
> The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class (§6.6).
>
> The default constructor has no formal parameters, except in a non-private  inner member class, where the default constructor implicitly declares one formal parameter representing the immediately enclosing instance of the class (§8.8.1, §15.9.2, §15.9.3).
>
> The default constructor has no throws clauses.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.

I've always thought that it needed to be also a **public constructor**, but today, while I was working with some JAXB mappings, I've decided to extract a static create method, and then the IDE has automatically turned my constructor into a private one.

**Edited**:

So I've realized that I don't need the no-args constructor anymore, and then removed it. So JAXB stopped working logging the following message:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.yourproject.YourClass does not have a no-arg default constructor.
```

The JAXB does work with a private no-args constructor, but when I remove it,  the above error message asking for a **no-args default constructor** is logged.

My question is: can a **private no-args constructor** also be called **default constructor**?

Here's my JAXB mapping (getters and setters omitted):

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "getagentstatus")
public class EccpGetAgentStatusRequest extends EccpAbstractRequest {

    public static EccpGetAgentStatusRequest create(String agentNumber) {
        return new EccpGetAgentStatusRequest(agentNumber);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "agent_number")
    private String agentNumber;

    private EccpGetAgentStatusRequest() {
    }

    private EccpGetAgentStatusRequest(String agentNumber) {
        this.agentNumber = agentNumber;
    }
}
```

The request wrapper:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
public class EccpRequestWrapper {
 
    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;
    
    @XmlAnyElement
    private IEccpRequest request;
    
    public void setRequest(IEccpRequest request) {
        this.id = request.getId();
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

and here's my test code:

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            EccpGetAgentStatusRequest wrapped = EccpGetAgentStatusRequest.create("Agent/1000");
            EccpRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new EccpRequestWrapper();
            requestWrapper.setRequest(wrapped);
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(EccpRequestWrapper.class, wrapped.getClass());
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.marshal(requestWrapper, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _Third edition_?! Please see the [current edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9); _The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class_.

Comment: Ok @Sotirios Delimanolis, updated to the current. But your comment doesn't answer my question. Could you pls read it again?

Comment: _and then the IDE has automatically turned my constructor into a private one_ Then it's not provided by the compiler and is not a default constructor. However, I do think the XML deserializer is looking for something `public` and has a misleading error message.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I've made a mistake while I was typing the question. Sorry. I've edited now. Thanks for your comment. It makes me realize my mistake.

Comment: JAXB works with private constructor but doesn't without it. It asks for a "no args default constructor" in the error message. That's the point: a private constructor is a default constructor or not. @Sotirios Delimanolis.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis. Wasn't it that I ask? Should I re-title the question our delete it? What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB needs a no-args constructor that it can call with reflection to create objects. JAXB doesn't care what the access on the constructor is because it's setting accessibility to true. So if you provide no constructor JAXB is fine because your class is given a default constructor. If you write your own private no-arg constructor JAXB is fine with that too. If you provide your own constructor that takes one or more arguments, and you don't provide a no-arg constructor, then no default constructor is created for the class and JAXB can't create objects of that class.

Terminology-wise, "default constructor" is defined in the quoted JLS passage to apply only to the constructor supplied by the compiler when you don't provide any. Using the term otherwise seems inaccurate.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan Hughes, firstly for understanding my point. Do you know if there's some JAXB docs about it?

Comment: @Jaumzera: i don't, i assume it documents what conventions its classes need to follow, similar to Hibernate.